# Rowindex of gridview by using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, navigateurl

I tried a lot of combinations to be able to get rowIndex in below code, What should be the written to below "THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PASS ROWINDEX " part.

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id,BookName" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                Width="800px" CssClass="Gridview">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BookName" SortExpression="BookName" ItemStyle-Width="250px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlk_Bookname" runat="server" Enabled='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Reserve")) %>'
                                Text='<%# Bind("BookName") %>' NavigateUrl='javascript:doYouWantTo("THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PASS ROWINDEX ")'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

..
..
..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx). The property [row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.aspx) contains the rowindex

**Code behind**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlk_Bookname"))
        .NavigateUrl=string.Format("javascript:doYouWantTo({0})",e.Row.RowIndex));
    }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1"
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
......
```

**Edit**

If there is a better solution for you problem. I think you are trying to invent the wheel again. I think you can have a look at [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event. You can use it in combination with [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx). You can see an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.commandsource.aspx). Or you can do it something like this:

**Code behind**

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="Add")
    {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];
      //What ever code you want to do....
    }
} 
//Set the command argument to the row index
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      LinkButton addButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
      addButton.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
    }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
              onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
              OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
              runat="server">

              <columns>
                <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" 
                  commandname="Add" 
                  text="Add"/>
```

Hope this help..

Comment: Thank you for the answer, may I ask you if my approach could be better?, I have hyperlinks in my gridview, when hyperlinks clicked, I display a javascript message (doYouWantTo as above), then if yes, this javascript code clicks an invisible asp.net button to run a c# function to insert the clicked row to database, So I asked the above question to find and pass rowindex to c# function, do you think is there any better way ?

Comment: As an alternative, if you wish to write all of it in the markup you can use this syntax:
    `onclick='<%#"myFunction(" + Container.DataItemIndex +")"%>'`